# How do I enable only a single Cloud SQL DB for a GCP service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-iam

I have a service account that should only have access to a single instance of Cloud SQL. In GCP, I've been trying to create a role with conditional access to the instance.

The instance name of the DB is test-sandboxy, and I've taken a screenshot of how I'm trying to create the role condition. [image]

Is there a prefix that I need to put on the name? Or is there a directory where I can look up resource names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud SQL does not support conditional role bindings.

[Resource types that accept conditional role bindings](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview#resources)

Comment: It looks like that Google Cloud SQL now supports conditions.
The name has to be in the format `projects/PROJECT_ID/instances/INSTANCE_ID` as described in https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/iam-conditions#allow_users_to_connect_to_specific_instances